# Is there any way to separate terraform's expression into multiple lines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to know the way to separate terraform expressions into multiple lines because they're sometimes too long if in 1 line.

- terraform's version I use

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.14.2
```

- long expression example : If the bucket name is not specified, create a new bucket name. If specified, use it.

```
locals {
  bucket_name = var.bucket_name == "" ? "hoge-${formatdate("YYYYMMDDHHmmss", timestamp())}" : var.bucket_name
}
```

- I want to change the example expression like below

```
locals {
  bucket_name = var.bucket_name == "" ? \
                "hoge-${formatdate("YYYYMMDDHHmmss", timestamp())}" : \
                 var.bucket_name
}
```

But this raise an `Error: Invalid expression`.

Is there any way to separate an expression into multiple lines?

Answer (score 7):

You can just put it in **brackets**:

```
locals {
  bucket_name = (var.bucket_name == "" 
              ? "hoge-${formatdate("YYYYMMDDHHmmss", timestamp())}" 
              : var.bucket_name)
}
```